# mutableDictionary used with UITableview: change its editable property

Tags: ios, xcode

Greeting. I have a tableView, of which content is from a dictionary. To load the content:

```
//For the table view content
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
    NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text=contentForThisRow;

   //cell.textLabel.text=[self.msgCourse objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

I want to make the row editable, say user can delete some rows:

```
//Below are for editting
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return YES;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

I know it must return error saying the `content not matching with the dictionary` when I delete it. So the best way to fix it is to fix my dictionary, is that true please? Any example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

The problem is that you are not doing what the comment says. You *didn't* delete the row from the data source (`self.sectionKeys` and `self.sectionContents`). You must do that *before* you delete the row from the table.

Comment: For discussion and example code, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_deleting_table_items

Comment: Hi, matt. Thanks for your reply. I am a newbie in IOS. What I don't know is how to delete datasource from my dictionary. How can I link it to self.sectionKeys and self.sectionContents please?